# Check if an SNS topic subscription is still valid for an SQS queue

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a SNS topic in one AWS account (topic account) and a SQS queue in another AWS account (queue account). The topic gives subscribe permission the queue account.

There are scenarios where the topic can get deleted and recreated, but when this happens the link between the topic and the queue gets severed. I need to re subscribe to the topic in order to start getting messages again.

I want to know if there is a method to detect this link being broken programmatically and how to re subscribe if this is the case. At a minimum I would like to know if the subscription is no longer valid.

I only have access to data that can be provided by the queue account, the topic account isn't in my ownership.

The [AWS SDK for .NET V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/) has a [queue client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/TSQSClient.html) but I was unable to find a useful way of getting this information. Searching through cloudshell to get some inspiration yielded no results.  I tried to get queue attributes with the below command:

```bash
aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url [URL_VALUE_IN_QUEUE_DETAILS]
```

This command didn't return any output and I'm not sure why.

I would like to get some suggestion what I should try next.